# Postgres, get two row values that are both linked to the same ID

Tags: postgresql, join, relationship

I have a rather tricky database problem that has really stumped me, would appreciate any help.

I have a table which includes data from multiple different sources. This data from different sources can be ‘duplicated’ and we have ways of identifying if that is the case.

Each row in the table has an ‘id’, and if it is identified as a duplicate of another row then we merge it, and it is given a ‘merged_into_id’ which refers to another row in the same table.

I am trying to run a report which will return information about where we have identified duplicates from two of those different sources.

Lets say I have three sources: A, B and C. I want to identify all of the duplicate rows between source A and source B.

I have got the query working fine to do this if a row from source A is directly merged into source B. However, we also have instances in the DB where source A row AND source B row are merged into source C. I am struggling with these and was hoping someone could help with that.

An example:

Original DB:

| id | source | merged_into_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 3 |
| 2 | B | 3 |
| 3 | C | NULL |

What I would like to do is to be able to return id 1 and id 2 from that table, as they are both merged into the same ID e.g. like so:

| source_a_id | source_b_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

But I'm really struggling to get to that - all I've managed to do is create a parent and child link like the following:

| parent_id | child_id | child_source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | A |
| 3 | 2 | B |

I can also return just the IDs that I want, but they don't 'join' so to speak:
e.g.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN child_source = 'A' then child_id as source_a_id,
    CASE WHEN child_source = 'B' then child_id as source_b_id
```

But that just gives me a response with an empty row for the 'missing' data

---EDIT---

Using `array_agg` and `array_to_string` I've gotten a little closer to what I need:

```
SELECT 
    parent.id as parent_id,
        ARRAY_TO_STRING(
        ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN child_source = 'A' THEN child.id END)
        , ','
    ) a_id,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(
        ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN child_source = 'B' THEN child.id END)
        , ','
    ) b_id
```

but its not quite the right format as I can occasionally have *multiple* versions from each source, so I get a table that looks like :

| parent_id | a_id | b_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 2,4,5 |

In this case, I want to return a table that looks like:

| parent_id | a_id | b_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 |

Does anyone have any advice on getting to my desired output? Many thanks

Comment: Is this supposed to work with a generic number of dupes? In other words, does the answer need to include `source_d_id` automatically if there had been a row with (4, D, 3)?

Comment: Thanks for the response - it does need to work on a generic number. I've edited the question to reflect this. I've also gotten (I think) a little bit further. Does the edit help at all? Cheers!

Comment: so if you have two duplicates in a and 3 duplicates in b , you want to show 6 rows?

Comment: yep that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that we have this table

```
 select * from t;
 id | source | merged_into_id 
----+--------+----------------
  1 | A      |              3
  2 | B      |              3
  3 | C      |               
  5 | B      |              3
  4 | B      |              3
(5 rows)
```

This should do the work

```
WITH B_source as (select * from t where source = 'B'),
     A_source as (select * from t where source = 'A')
SELECT merged_into_id,A_source.id as a_id,B_source.id as b_id 
FROM A_source 
INNER JOIN B_source using (merged_into_id);
```

Result

```
 merged_into_id | a_id | b_id 
----------------+------+------
              3 |    1 |    2
              3 |    1 |    5
              3 |    1 |    4
(3 rows)
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! Thank you so much, really appreciate it